# Cannot open assembly '/usr/lib/mono/4.5/xsp2.exe': No such file or directory

Tags: centos7, xsp

I need your help,i use 'yum' command to install xsp by this following command,

```
sudo yum install xsp
```

then i tried to ensure that xsp is installed or not,

```
[root@vultr src]# xsp -v
Cannot open assembly '/usr/lib/mono/4.5/xsp2.exe': No such file or directory.
```

can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
yum remove xsp
yum install xsp-4.2-2.el7.x86_64
```

or run this to see what is available (I could not find any `xsp2.exe`):

```
yum whatprovides /usr/lib/mono/4.5/*
```

Comment: EXM? I can't get you idea.

Comment: just run `repoquery --list xsp` to see that there is no `xsp2.exe`.

Comment: I do run `repoquery --list xsp` and found no `xsp2.exe`

Comment: @ShaohuaZhou so do you realize the problem with that `xsp` package? it's broken and most likely quite outdated... `xsp-4.2-2` at least would provide `xsp4.exe`.